# How do I get a Java maven build to fail for compiler warnings?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-construction, build, lint

I am trying:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but with no joy. Any ideas now to get medieval on such errors as suggested at  [this blog post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/tball/archive/2006/11/get_medieval_on.html)?

Comment: There was a bug as is mentioned below that is no longer a problem. This form as specified with the compilerArgument works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This answer is outdated however I can't delete it as it was an accepted answer at the time.

This a bug with Maven see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-120 it's been fixed in 2.4 of the Maven-compiler-plugin but I don't believe that's been released yet.  tag won't work either unfortunately.

Comment: maven-compiler-plugin 2.4 is already released to Maven Central

Comment: Yep, but it wasn't when I made the answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, this bug isn't a problem any longer and the form specified in the question works great.

Answer (score 34):

Update for the year 2015, using Maven 3.3 and Java 8.

Here's a minimal compiler configuration that enables all warnings and makes
the build fail whenever warnings occur.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                <arg>-Werror</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Bits of note:

- `<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>` is required. For reasons unknown, Maven by default actively suppresses warnings with the `-nowarn` flag, so the `-Xlint` and `-Werror` flags would be ignored.
- `showDeprecation` doesn't need to be enabled because `-Xlint:all` already emits deprecation warnings.
- Experimentation shows that `fork` doesn't need to be enabled, even though the
  documentation says otherwise.

Comment: I like to leave out the `groupId` for built-in Maven plugins to emphasise their special standing as built-ins. The built-in Maven plugins all have the default group ID `org.apache.maven.plugins`, so it isn’t necessary to specify it in the POM. (Try `mvn help:effective-pom` to verify this.)

Answer (score 9):

New in `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.6.0: the `failOnWarning` flag. This worked for me:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>compile</id>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:-processing</compilerArgument>
          <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Note that I had to exclude the `processing` lint or otherwise auto-matter's annotations would break the build with cryptic "symbol not found" errors.

Comment: The above answer works, though I tried making it work without the `-Xlint` setting and that was not successful. I found `<failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>` is the same as `<compilerArgs> <arg>-Werror</arg>`. By itself `-Werror` doesn't do anything as it needs to be paired with `-Xlint:all`. So by itself `<failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>` doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 4):

An update on 2020, I am using Spring Boot 2.2.5. The following config can stop the `mvn install` when warning, error happen.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate form perhaps give it a try? Note the s on the end of `<compilerArguments>`

```
<configuration>
    <compilerArguments>
        <Werror />
    </compilerArguments>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the workaround in [this comment](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-120?focusedCommentId=281147&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-281147) in the [open jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-120) for maven compiler plugin, the build can be failed for compiler warning.

This works for me:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerId>javac</compilerId>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>

        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
                <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-component-api</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-manager</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
                <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-component-api</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-component-api</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
          </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this post when I was looking for a working solution to fail my maven builds for compiler warnings

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-Werror</arg> 
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For more explanation in detail please refer the link below

[Treat warnings As Errors](https://www.aravindhu.com/software%20development/2021/03/18/treat-warnings-as-errors-in-java.html)