# Make Maven test fail on warnings

Tags: maven

How to make `mvn test` goal fail if ANY warning is detected?

I have tried without success:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand that cause you have already turned on failOnWarning ? What does not work? Logging output ? example pom file? etc. ?

Comment: I tried that, but the goal succeeds even when there exist warnings

Comment: Please an example with code and full pom file..

Comment: it is no relevant, what I want to know if there is a way to fail when there are warnings

Comment: It is relevant to understand your problem but if you don't like me neither...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192613/how-do-i-get-a-java-maven-build-to-fail-for-compiler-warnings