# How to resolve/disable -Werrors in java projects?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my Java maven project, when I try compiling the project in IntelliJ , it gives the error

```
Error: java warnings found and -Werror specified
```

I have found that -Werrors are caused due to warnings being shown as errors. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building your project with the -Werror flag. That flag treats warnings as errors and therefore makes the build fail. You can either remove the flag from your build options or solve the warnings.

Comment: Why does this error show only for some warnings and not others ?

Comment: That I do not know. At least not without knowing what warnings are not being treated as errors by the flag in your case.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, I searched the word '-Werror' in my project and found it in build.sbt under javaOptions. After commenting it is working fine. Thanks @JustAnotherDeveloper.

Comment: Here one can read the exactly maven properties (and their values) that would cause this error to happen. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33823355/7066647